# Maven plugin prefix resolution doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: maven

I've created a MOJO for a specific application need. I've followed maven's [guidelines](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) in naming the plugin so that I didn't have to mention the full

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal
```

for executing my plugin(I've named it to match the format ${prefix}-maven-plugin).
I've even included the 'goalPrefix' property in the plugin POM's configuration section. Here's a sniff of what I did to my plugin's POM:

```
<configuration>
  <goalPrefix>${prefix}</goalPrefix>
</configuration>
```

But I'm still unable to execute my plugin just using `mvn ${prefix}:goal` since it complains it can't find the plugin in any repository. I've still had to use `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal` Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Maven does only recognize plugins with the group IDs `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`. If your plugin has a different group ID (which should be the case), you need to add this group ID as plugin group to your Maven settings.xml file:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>the.groupid.of.my.plugin</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  ...
</settings>
```

Take a look at the [Maven Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups) for further details.

Comment: Yep, you were absolutely right, maven only seems to recognize plugins whose group IDs are those of maven and codehaus plugins and mine was of course different. That helped a lot, cheers.  EDIT: you know how I try and execute a default goal if not specified in the command line? Like just using `mvn plugin` instead of `mvn plugin:goal`.

Comment: @mystarrocks There is no such thing as default goals. However, maven knows the concept of [lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), such as `compile`, `test`, `install`, etc. A maven plugin can be bound to such a lifecycle phase. For example, if you bind your plugin to the `package` phase, you can just run `mvn package` instead of `mvn <yourplugin>:<goal>`.